# Multiple record insert using single model

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to insert multiple records.Here is my ci=ontroller code :

```
if(empty($this->data) == false)
            {
                for($i=0;$i<=count($this->data['Breakdown']);$i++)
                {
                    echo count($this->data['Breakdown']);
                    $this->Breakdown->create(); 
                    if($this->Breakdown->save($this->data)) 
                    {

                         $this->Session->setFlash('Quantity Breakdown has been added Successfully.', 'default', array('class' => 'oMsg1 oMsgError1'));
                         //$this->redirect('qty_breakdown');
                    } 
                }

            }
            else
             {
              $this->set('errors', $this->Breakdown->invalidFields());   
             }
```

my problem is that if i put only one value in text fields,it inserted records eight time.I want a solution to insert it perfect using this code?

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($this->data) in the controller before the `for` and update this question with the output?

Comment: One mistake at least is that you are saving the *same* data each time - you are looping over `$this->data['Breakdown']` but you're *saving* `$this->data` each time.

Answer (score 1):

## Saving multiple records via Model::saveMany()

You don't have to manually loop over your data, CakePHP models are able to handle all this automatically, as long as you create your forms according to the CakePHP conventions

### Creating the right Form-inputs via the FormHelper

For this to work correctly, your posted data should be according to the CakePHP conventions;

For example: create your form-inputs like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Breakdown.1.field1');
echo $this->Form->input('Breakdown.1.field2');

// ....

echo $this->Form->input('Breakdown.99.field1');
echo $this->Form->input('Breakdown.99.field2');
```

Which, when debugging the posted data inside the controller, should look like this:

```
debug($this->request->data);

array(
    'Breakdown' => array(
        (int) 1 => array(
            'field1' => 'value of field1 in row 1',
            'field2' => 'value of field2 in row 1'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'field1' => 'value of field1 in row 2',
            'field2' => 'value of field2 in row 2'
        )
    )
)
```

### Saving the data - Controller code

Then, inside your controller:

```
public function qty_breakdown()
{
    $this->layout = 'common';

    if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->data['Breakdown'])) {
        if ($this->Breakdown->saveMany($this->data['Breakdown'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                'Quantity Breakdown has been added Successfully.',
                'default',
                array('class' => 'oMsg1 oMsgError1')
            );
            $this->redirect('qty_breakdown');
        } else {
            // NOTE: If you're using the FormHelper, you DON'T
            // have to do this, the FormHelper will automatically
            // mark invalid fields 'invalid'
            $this->set('errors', $this->Breakdown->invalidFields());

            // However, it's Good practice to set a general error message
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to save your data');
        }
    }
}
```

### The documentation

This part of the documentation describes [Model::saveMany()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)